# I am new in web scraping using casperjs try to run some example problem but doesn't get the result

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

So first I try with this code which is available in casperjs example for scraping google search result. but it doesn't work correctly.

```
var links = [];
var casper = require('casper').create();

function getLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('h3.r a');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
        return e.getAttribute('href');
    });
}

casper.start('http://google.fr/', function() {
   // Wait for the page to be loaded
   this.waitForSelector('form[action="/search"]');
});

casper.then(function() {
   // search for 'casperjs' from google form
   this.fill('form[action="/search"]', { q: 'casperjs' }, true);
});

casper.then(function() {
    // aggregate results for the 'casperjs' search
    links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
    // now search for 'phantomjs' by filling the form again
    this.fill('form[action="/search"]', { q: 'phantomjs' }, true);
});

casper.then(function() {
    // aggregate results for the 'phantomjs' search
    links = links.concat(this.evaluate(getLinks));
});

casper.run(function() {
    // echo results in some pretty fashion
    this.echo(links.length + ' links found:');
    this.echo(' - ' + links.join('\n - ')).exit();
});
```

Yes, it failed like this. And I get this in my cmd ...

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

F:\WEBSCRAPING\CasperScripts>casperjs google.js

F:\WEBSCRAPING\CasperScripts>0 links found:
```

Comment: I never worked with casperjs so I don't know how they handle redirects, but I think that may be the issue. Visiting google website with an HTTP connection will redirect you to an HTTPS connection. Did you try accessing `https://www.google.fr/` directly within your code?

Comment: ok thanks for this one, I will try it right away...